# Fault with -moz- -webkit- -o- in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, magento, safari, webkit

I am using magento for my eCommerce website and I'm trying to set up a slider panel from this site: https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-slide-in-panel/.

The problem I have on this 2 browsers that the slider goes under certain parts of the site. At the beginning I thought it is z-index problem but it's not,in chrome console it crosses out all of the webkit and moz.It works perfectly fine in Mozilla  Would anyone be able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it will cross out all off prefixed properties is because they are either not required or no longer supported.

It is more than likely in your case that the prefixes are no longer required because they are built in fully into CSS.

As an example, `box-shadow` required a prefix before becoming a built in element.

```
Browser  -  Prefix  -  Un-prefixed
----------------------------------
Chrome   -   1.0    -     10.0 
Firefox  -   3.5    -      4.0
Safari   -   3.0    -      5.1
```

If you look at the below demo in the Chrome inspector or Firebug, you will see the prefixed versions are commented out because they are no longer required.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

In terms of your problem, I would guess that the issue is an element stacking issue.

- Check `z-index` of all elements
- Make sure the code for this is at the bottom of the screen
- Use the chrome element selector to see what elements are overlaying and why

Comment: I've got to say you were right , however I have the panel button in my header. I've put it at the bottom of the header and it overlays the header but it is behind the main content of the site , any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: Like i said, put it below everything. If you cant do that, then add `position: relative;` to the main content and make sure the `z-index` is below the sliding panels.

Comment: Thank you very much I have left the button to trigger panel in header and moved all the rest all the way down to the footer and It works perfectly. Thank you once more